# Can't run or pull windows docker images

Tags: windows, docker

From [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-base-os-images) I can't pull or run any windows docker image (from windows or Linux)

When trying from Windows cmd:

Pull:

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: manifest for mcr.microsoft.com/windows:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest tagged by "latest" is not found
```

Run:

```
docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1903
Unable to find image 'mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1903' locally
1903: Pulling from windows
docker: no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`docker: no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries.` means this image can just works on windows platform.

Although you works on windows, default `docker desktop` may use `linux container`, you should switch to `windows container` before pull this image using next at desktop tray with mouse right click the docker icon:

[image]

After switch, you could pull that image successfully:

```
C:\Windows\System32>docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1903
1903: Pulling from windows
af1a530dff54: Downloading [==========>                                      ]    738MB/3.657GB                        
123ee413bb26: Downloading [===================>                               ]  994.8MB/2.51GB
```

BTW, looks `latest` label not set for this image, so you will have to use detail version, e.g. 19.03.

Comment: +1 great! this works!  just wondering, is there a programmatic way to do this? for instance `docker system --switch-to-windows`?

Comment: Try `"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchDaemon`, other parameters is `-SwitchLinuxEngine`, `-SwitchWindowsEngine`